# Can I give a function to a label?

Tags: macros, labels

I try to create a dynamic way to give labels to my slides in Beamer.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand{\partName}{blank}
\newcommand {\defPartName}[1]{\renewcommand{\partName}{#1}}

%\includeonlyframes{firstChapter}
\begin{document}

\defPartName{firstChapter}
\begin{frame}[label=\partName]{A title}
The label of the current frame is \partName .
\end{frame}

\defPartName{secondChapter}
\begin{frame}[label=\partName]{A title}
The label of the current frame is \partName .
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The macro works, because the frames display the correct name of the current label. But they don't seem to "receive" the label, because when I use the `\includeonlyframes{}`, it doesn't work (which is precisely why I want to use it).

Any idea?

Comment: Just to make sure: doesn't `\includeonlysection` exist? (I dunno, I just try to find a natural way how to do what you do `:-)` )

Comment: I precisely don't think so. But of course, I would be happy to use a more 'natural' way to do that :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible if you add `fragile` to your `frame`s

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand{\partName}{blank}
\newcommand {\defPartName}[1]{\renewcommand{\partName}{#1}}

\includeonlyframes{firstChapter}
\begin{document}

\defPartName{firstChapter}
\begin{frame}[fragile,label=\partName]{A title}
The label of the current frame is \partName .
\end{frame}

\defPartName{secondChapter}
\begin{frame}[fragile,label=\partName]{A title}
The label of the current frame is \partName .
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Ok thanks. But are there any consequences I should be aware of by using the 'fragile' option?

Comment: I've edited my post to show an issue I have with this solution...

Comment: @BonyHoax If you insert the code inside `\chapterFrame` directly in the document it works. It might be an expansion problem, but I can't figure out what it is.