# Substitute \chapter in Book with \lecture in Beamer

Tags: beamer, books, beamerarticle

**The question**

How can we "translate" automatically chapters in `book` to lectures in `Beamer`  to avoid  the legitimate `Undefined control sequence \chapter` when compiling a presentation ?

**The context**

I have a very long presentation (~ 2000 frames) splitted in 20 lectures. Thanks to a `beamerarticle` and `if 0\Article \documentclass{article} else \documentclass{beamer}` at the beginning of my code, I manage to have a good process to compile, either in a form of an article or in a presentation.

My document had the following structure

- Part 1

  - Section 1
  - Section 2
  - etc

It was working very well until I needed to restructure my document and realize a `book` (with chapters) made more sense.

- Part 1

  - Chapter 1

    - Section 1
    - Section 2
  - Chapter 2
  - etc

Thanks to [Lecture/chapters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159172/build-kind-of-a-includeonlypart-for-beamer) I understand the right "bridge" from `book` to `Beamer` (to avoid errors from `Beamer` not recognizing `\chapters`) would be to translate Chapters in `book` to Lectures in `Beamer`.

- Part 1

  - Chapter 1  => Lecture 1

    - Section 1
    - Section 2
  - Chapter 2  => Lecture 2
  - etc

thanks for your help :)

Comment: I don't understand the code `if 0\Article \documentclass{article} else \documentclass{beamer}`. What is processing it? Not (La)TeX. Why not, in the `else` portion, include `\let\chapter=\lecture`?

Comment: At the very beginning of the preambule, I defined `\def\Article{1}`. I decide whether I want an article (`\Article{1}`) and i load `\documentclass{article}` or a beamer (`\Article{0}`)  `\documentclass{beamer}.` It worked well  to switch from one to the other since both article and beamer mode have parts but no chapter.
As for the `\let\chapter=\lecture`, does it mean all the `\chapter` will be interpeted as `\lecture` in beamer ? As simple as that ? :)

Comment: @DonaldArseneau Would not there be a problem using `\let` since `\lecture{First Lecture}{firstChapter}` requires 2 arguments ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typing as a comment was too messy. OK, so the document uses `\if` and `\else` and `\fi`, and LaTeX handles it; although the usage seems backwards (you probably meant `\if 1\Article` for `\documentclass{article}`).

Yeah, you no-doubt want to type `\lecture` in the document, and convert it to `\chapter`, rather than translating chapter => lecture, and not with `\let`.  So

```
\def\Book{1}% or 0, or use optional.sty!
\if 1\Book
  \documentclass[your options]{book}% or scrbook etc.
  \newcommand\lecture[3][\shortlecname]{% 
    \def\shortlecname{#2}% default for TOC and header
    \chapter[#1]{#2}\label{#3}}
\else 
   \documentclass{beamer}
   \AtBeginLecture{ 
     blah blah a frame like a chapter
   }
\fi
```

Don't use `\includeonlylecture`. Then, in the document body

```
\lecture{Exciting stuff}{excite}
```

Comment: Merci Donald ! the code worked well but after a second compilation I go an `! LaTeX Error: Command \lecture already defined`. Also, given the synthax `\lecture{Exciting stuff}{excite}`, should not it be `\newcommand\lecture[3][\shortlecname]{
    \def\shortlecname{#2}
    \chapter[#2]{#1}\label{#3}}` ?

Comment: I can't guess where you have a double definition of `\lecture`. It does not happen in simple tests. And, no, it is `\chapter[#1]{#2}\label{#3}` That also covers the actual defined syntax with optional arguments (where #1 is the optional short name in both the lecture and the chapter case). I didn't know if you wanted to do anything with the third argument, so I used it for a `\label`.